# Alias function across redshift datashare

Tags: amazon-redshift

With redshift datashare I can do

```
create view myschema.mytable as 
select * from myshare.myschema.mytable 
with no schema binding
```

That'll give me access to the table with the same exact syntax, but I can't do

```
create function myschema.myfunc(character varying)
 returns character varying immutable language sql
as $$ select myshare.myschema.myfunc($1) $$
```

Is there any way around this so I don't need to keep referring to it as `myshare.myschema.myfunc` and can just use `myschema.myfunc` in the other db?